# Are there any text-based progress bar implementations?

Tags: c++, terminal, text-based

I'm trying to create a terminal-based backup program and I'm looking for some C++ code that creates a text-based progress bar. I understand you can implement it yourself with \b but I thought I'd see if there is any well-built implementations already. My favourite implementation of a text-based progress bar is pacman's progress bar on arch linux.

My project is created with C++ (Qt4).

Comment: try ncurses that's a really good library for this, not sure if it has the exact type of bar you want

Comment: @Jesus Ramos, I'm not sure about ncurses; once you use it a small amount, your entire project is an ncurses project. It doesn't co-exist well with std input's and output's

Answer (score 3):

The [Boost Timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/timer/timer.htm) library has a progress timer display.

Comment: It looks promising, but a progress bar that could fit on one line with possibly a label would be perfect; It's good but for many different bars, can be a bit much

Comment: That library is deprecated.